# listCollections is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I need to take all collections and output them to the console. For this I use listCollections. In server.js I have connected firebase and set up the server and in the script.js file I am making requests to Firestore. But now in the console the error is db.listCollections is not a function. How can I fix this?

server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./key/controlling-expenses-app-firebase-adminsdk-m1li2-fd742a3adb.json");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL:
    "...",
});

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = { admin, db };

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port: ${PORT}`));
```

script.js

```js
const getAllUsers = () => {
  db.listCollections()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((snaps) => {
        console.log(snaps["_queryOptions"].collectionId); // LIST OF ALL COLLECTIONS
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};
getAllUsers();
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use `firestore` for managing database instead of `firebase-admin`
2. Understand firestore structure:
   `db > collections > documents > collections > ...`

The listCollections() method of the Cloud Firestore server client libraries lists all subcollections of a document reference, not queries from db

```
import { ref, onUnmounted } from 'vue';
const getAllUsers = () => {
  const users = ref([]);
  const q = query(collection(db, 'users'));
  const close = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    users.value = snapshot.docs.map(docItem => ({ id: docItem.id, ...docItem.data() }));
  });
  onUnmounted(close);
  return users;
}
```